# How can I read COMM ports from Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, comm

I have a Laptop with no COMM ports,
and I need to upgrade a software that read a scale device with RS-232.

I'm using VSPE to emulate a COMM PORT , but this lines returns to me nulls;

```
    Enumeration ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    System.out.println("start Port List scanner");
    while(ports.hasMoreElements())
```

I guess this is because eclipse cant't find the windows dll.
win32com.dll
or 
rxtxSerial.dll

I have to copy to Java Lib and Windows/System32 folder ?
Is there any way to tell eclipse where to find those dll ?

Best Regards

Comment: Configure the folder that contains the DLLs in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Libraries_ in the _Native library location_ subnodes of the corresponding JAR.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add comm-2.0.jar to your project. [download](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomm20jar.htm)

Or you can add it as a dependency to your pom.xml if you're handling a maven project:

[link for maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.comm/comm/2.0.3)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.comm</groupId>
    <artifactId>comm</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I don't know why but when i post dependency xml , the closing tag of dependency won't show up.

Comment: Thank you @Akceptor  for helping out about answer formatting. :) But the second line is not an example for the first line.